# Trying to pass in an array of associative arrays in form data

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, multipartform-data

I'm trying to pass in an array of associative arrays inside a form data but when i return all the request from my laravel backend that specific array is null. Here is my code ->

```js
let add1 = [];

$("#add1").click(function () {

    let name = $("input[name='value']").val();

    let currentArray = [];

    currentArray["name"] = name;

    add1.push(currentArray);

    formData.append("add1", add1);
});

// Result: Getting null.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Associative arrays are not a thing in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have associative array as @charles-bamford pointed out. It only has numeric [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). In your case, you want to use an object.

Furthermore, [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)'s [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) method only accepts primitive values so you have to serialize the object.

```js
let add1 = [];

$("#add1").click(function () {

    let name = $("input[name='value']").val();

    let currentArray = {};

    currentArray["name"] = name;

    add1.push(currentArray);

    formData.append("add1", JSON.stringify(add1));
});

// Result: Getting null.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm actually now passing in a array of objects but it takes it as a string even after i JSON.stringify() it.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` returns a string. What's wrong with that? `add1` is `[{"name":"Test"}]`